# Fetching data from wordpress database on table hover

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

Im currently using Events Manager Plugin for wordpress on a split column layout, which displays the events in a table in left colum of the page. And i want to be able to fetch the additional information linked to a event and display it in the right column when hovering over the events in the table. (Maybe using jquery or ajax?)

I found a tutorial in the documentation(http://wp-events-plugin.com/tutorials/adding-information-to-events-on-load/) which allows certain data to be displayed on load. But i want to display the data dynamically on hover events. But i dont think this is what i'll be needing.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use AJAX for this.

You could so something like:

```
$('#table').on('hover', function(e) {
    $.get({
        // AJAX parameters here
    });
});
```

Then on success of the AJAX function you can update the table data. If you're not familiar with using AJAX in WP, check out this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Here is some information on the jQuery `$.get()` function: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: this actually got me pretty far. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Appreciate it!